# better way to do deal with parent ul width in dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

I have seen a lots of horizontal menu where the dropdown have a fixed width like this http://www.dubspot.com/ it's work but…

I try to make a logical size, width like parent or more. 
My solution http://jsfiddle.net/m2ry3/ but it's a little bit creepy (duplicate would be using jQuery):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">very long item like this</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">small item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">small item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">small item 3</a></li>
    <!--duplicate and hidden -->
    <li class="hack"><a href="#">very long item like this</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">small</a>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">a long item 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">a various item 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">small 3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```

```
ul li{
    float:left;
}
ul li a{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
    text-decoration:none;
    border:1px solid #eee;

}
ul ul{
 position:absolute;       
 background:#ddd;
 display:block;   
}

.hack{
visibility:hidden;
height:0;    
}
ul li ul li {
    display:block;  
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
}
```

with hover effect in jQuery (I know how).
Is it possible to adjust width without js (jQuery) ? or there is a CSS tips ?

I try without a duplicate li, it's not easy to deal with li outerwidth (border, padding)…

Answer (score 0):

If you want adjust text within fix width of li then you can use css property -

word-wrap: break-word;

by this you can adjust long text within fixed width.

i think this will help you